# Display image fetched from database by a Servlet to JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jdbc

I am working on a java web application named 'StudentConnectJSP'. I have to store information of a user along with an uploaded photo fetched from index.jsp to a database 't' using servlet 'CreateAccount.java'. i have a servlet 'ImageFetch' to fetch the image from database. Now when i try to display the image from 'ImageFetch' to home.jsp, it doesn't work. Here's the code.

index.html

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
         <H1>CREATE ACCOUNT</H1>
     <br>
     <form action="CreateAccount" method="post" 
     enctype = "multipart/form-        data">
     NAME
     <br>
     <input class="in" type="text" placeholder="FIRST NAME" name="fname">
     <input class="in" type="text" placeholder="LAST NAME" name="lname">
     <br>
     ROLL NO.<br>
     <input class="in" type="text" name="roll">
     <br>
     UNIVERSITY
             <input type="text" name="univ"><br>
     COLLEGE<br>
     <input class="in" type="text" name="college">
     <BR>
             PHOTO<input type="file" name="photo">
     <br>
     GENDER <br>
     <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">MALE
     <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">FEMALE
     <br>
     create password<br>
     <input class="in" type="TEXT" placeholder="PASWORD" name="pass">
     <input id="sub" type="submit" value="signin">
     </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

CreateAccount.java

```
package com.studentconnect;

import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

@WebServlet("/uploadServlet")
@MultipartConfig(maxFileSize = 16177215)
public class CreateAccount extends HttpServlet {

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws    
IOException, ServletException{

    res.setContentType("text/html");

    int flag = 0;
    String n;

    String fname = req.getParameter("fname");
    String lname = req.getParameter("lname");
    int rno = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("roll"));
    String pass = req.getParameter("pass");
    String univ = req.getParameter("univ");
    String college = req.getParameter("college");
    String sex = (req.getParameter("sex"));

    InputStream is = null;

    Part filePart = req.getPart("photo");
    if (filePart != null) {
        is = filePart.getInputStream();
    }

    PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
    out.print("<html><body>");
    out.print("<b>Servlet Started</b>");
    out.print("<p>" + is + "</p>");
    out.print("<p>" + rno + "</p>");

    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con =      
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/student", "root", 
"root");
        if(!con.isClosed()){
            System.out.println("Connected to MySQL");

            Statement stmt=con.createStatement();  
            stmt.executeUpdate("create table if not exists t(id int(10) NOT 
NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, fname varchar(10), lname varchar(10), rno int(10), 
photo mediumblob, univ varchar(25), college varchar(25), sex varchar(5), 
pass varchar(20), PRIMARY KEY(id))");
            String sql = "insert into t (fname, lname, rno, photo, univ, 
college, sex, pass) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
            PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.setString(1, fname);
            pst.setString(2, lname);
            pst.setInt(3, rno);
            if(is != null){
                pst.setBlob(4, is);
            }
            pst.setString(5, univ);
            pst.setString(6, college);
            pst.setString(7, sex);
            pst.setString(8, pass);
            int i = pst.executeUpdate();
            if(i > 0){
                    HttpSession session = req.getSession(true); 
        session.setAttribute("user", fname);
        session.setMaxInactiveInterval(30);
                    //RequestDispatcher rd = 
req.getRequestDispatcher("ImageFetch");
                    //rd.forward(req,res);
                    res.sendRedirect("home.jsp");
            }
            else{
                    RequestDispatcher rd = 
req.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
        out.println("<font color=red>Either user name or password is wrong.
</font>");
        rd.include(req, res);
            }
            out.print("<p>Account successfully created.</p>");
        }
        con.close();
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException c){
        System.out.println(c);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
   out.print("</body></html>");

}

}
```

home.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"    
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"    
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<br>
<%
    if (session != null) {
        if (session.getAttribute("user") != null) {
            String name = (String) session.getAttribute("user");
            out.print("Hello, " + name + "  Welcome to ur Profile");
                            out.print("<hr>");
        } else {
            response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
        }
    }
%>
</br>
    <img src="/StudentConnectJSP/ImageFetch"/>
</br>
    <form action="ImageFetch" method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="Show">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

ImageFetch.java

```
package com.studentconnect;

import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class ImageFetch extends  HttpServlet{
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
response) throws ServletException, IOException{
String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/student";
java.sql.Connection con=null;
try{  
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
con=DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL,"root","root");  
Statement st1=con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs1 = st1.executeQuery("select photo from"+
" t where id='2'");
String imgLen="";
if(rs1.next()){
imgLen = rs1.getString(1);
System.out.println(imgLen.length());
}  
rs1 = st1.executeQuery
("select photo from t where id='2'");
if(rs1.next()){
int len = imgLen.length();
byte [] rb = new byte[len];
InputStream readImg = rs1.getBinaryStream(1);
int index=readImg.read(rb, 0, len);  
System.out.println("index"+index);
st1.close();
response.reset();

response.setContentType("image/jpg");

response.getOutputStream().write(rb,0,len);
RequestDispatcher RequetsDispatcherObj   
=request.getRequestDispatcher("/home.jsp");
  RequetsDispatcherObj.forward(request, response);
  response.getOutputStream().flush();
  }
  }
  catch (Exception e){
  e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
```